# python - How to deploy Flask+Gunicorn+Nginx+supervisor on a cloud server?

Tags: python, nginx, web, flask, server

I've read a lot of instructions since yesterday about this issue but all of them have similar steps. However I followed step by step but still can't get everything Ok.

Actually I can make Flask+Gunicorn+supervisor working but Nginx is not working well.

I connect my remote cloud server with SSH and I'm not deploying the site on my computer.

Nginx is installed correctly because when I visit the site via the domain name (aka. `example.com`) it shows the Nginx welcome page.

I use `supervisor` to start Gunicorn and the configuration is

```
[program:myapp]
command=/home/fh/test/venv/bin/gunicorn -w4 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 myapp:app
directory=/home/fh/test
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=0
autostart=false
autorestart=false
stdout_logfile=/home/fh/test/log/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/home/fh/test/log/gunicorn.err
```

here I bind the server to port **8000** and **I don't actually know what does 0.0.0.0 stand for but I think it doesn't mean the localhost because I can visit the site via *http://example.com:8000* and it works well.**

Then I tried to use Nginx as a proxy server.

I deleted `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default' and '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default/` and created `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.com` and symlink them.

`test.com`

```
server {
        server_name www.penguin-penpen.com;
        rewrite ^ http://example/ permanent;
}

# Handle requests to example.com on port 80
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        # Handle all locations
        location / {
                # Pass the request to Gunicorn
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

                # Set some HTTP headers so that our app knows where the request really came from
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

To my understanding, what Nginx do is when I visit `http://example.com` it passes my request to `http://example.com:8000`.

I'm not quite sure that I should use `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000` here because I don't know whether should Nginx pass the request to localhost **But I 've tried to change it to `0.0.0.0:8000` but it still doesn't work.**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0` means the server will accept connections from all IP address. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0 for more detail.

If the gunicorn server listens on `127.0.0.1`, only you (or someone else on the same machine with gunicorn server) can access it through local loop https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_loop.

But since you use Nginx to accept connection from the internet, you can just `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` and change the command to `command=/home/fh/test/venv/bin/gunicorn -w4 -b 127.0.0.1:8000 myapp:app`. In this scenario, gunicorn itself only need to accept connections from Nginx which runs on the same machine with gunicorn.

The whole process looks like this

```
Connections from the Internet -> Nginx (reverse proxy, listen on 0.0.0.0:80) -> Gunicorn (which runs your Python code, listen on 127.0.0.1:8000)
```